# How to show breadcrumbs only if I don't specify the option on the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have my breadcrumbs working with the gem, but I am not sure how can I control its output. Right now, I want to add something like this in the view `- show_breadcrumbs false` and then have it not show, but I am not really sure how am I supposed to do this. I am not too familiar with yield/blocks. Could someone show me how I can write this?

Here was my attempt:

In my helper:

```
  def show_breadcrumbs(show=true)
    if show
      render :partial => 'layouts/breadcrumbs'
    end
  end
```

In my application.html.haml:
`= yield :show_breadcrumbs`

In my view:
`- show_breadcrumbs false`

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [`yield` and `content_for`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield) methods:

In the layout `application.html.haml`:

```
= content_for?(:breadcrumbs) ? yield(:breadcrumbs) : render(:partial => 'layouts/breadcrumbs') %>
```

This will render the breadcrumbs by default, unless you specify otherwise in the view:

```
content_for(:breadcrumbs, '')  # to hide the breadcrumbs.
```

or

```
content_for(:breadcrumbs, 'anything else')  # to replace breadcrumbs with something else.
```

Comment: I wanted to go for a show be default and only show when I explicitly state it. I didn't want to put `content_for(:breadcrumbs, show_breadcrumbs)` in all my views. Is there a way I can achieve that using content_for?

Comment: @Strawberry I've updated my answer so breadcrumbs is displayed by default.